# Update MapView/MapController from AsyncTask?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, android-mapview

I'm making my first Android app, which on initial load determines the user's current location and goes to it in a MapView. I've delegated initializing the MapView/MapController to an AsyncTask to make the app feel more responsive, but I'm getting a RuntimeException in my doInBackground method. Here's the code for my initial Activity and the AsyncTask which I'm using.

```
public class MainActivity extends MapActivity {

Location latestLocation, targetLocation;
MapController mapController;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Get a reference to the MapView
    MapView myMapView = (MapView)findViewById(R.id.myMapView);

    MapLoader map = new MapLoader();
    try {
        map.execute(myMapView).get();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    mapController = myMapView.getController();
    //code which determines current location and animates to it in the Mapview.
}
}
```

And here's the code for my AsyncTask.

```
public class MapLoader extends AsyncTask<MapView ,Void, Void>{

MapController mapController;
MapView mapView;

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(MapView... params) {
    // Get the Map View’s controller
    mapController = params[0].getController();
    // Configure the map display options
    mapView.setSatellite(true);
    mapView.displayZoomControls(false);
    // Zoom in
    mapController.setZoom(19);
    return null;


}
```

}

Should I put the code for determining the location inside the AsyncTask as well? Currently, my app is pretty slow on loading, as well as being quite unresponsive even after everything's initialized.

Comment: Sorry, that `AsyncTask` makes no sense. You have to control the UI from the UI thread or it will crash in most cases. Downloading data, disk access, database access & long running calculations is what you do async.

Comment: Is there no way to make my MapView be controlled by an AsyncTask? The reason I'm doing this is because my app is really slow as the UI thread initializes the MapView.

Comment: No, at least not from inside `doInBackground`. If there is something that makes your app unresponsive it's not the few lines that set options for your `MapView`.